# Spring-security jars download manually

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I  am trying to write the spring security hello world example, I am searching for the spring security jars to download manually, I had look  [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) Seems there is no way to download them manually. It shows the way to add dependency though Maven.

Please suggest official link from where I can download the spring-security jars.

[This](http://spring.io/projects?project=Spring%2520Security&version=3.1.2.RELEASE) shows all the projects in spring

> SPRING FRAMEWORK 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository at http://repo.spring.io is browseable and searchable. But really you should be using an automated dependency manager. What's the problem?

Comment: I am not much familiar with Maven, I have used Ant extensively.

Comment: then maybe you can try out ivy? https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/start.html

Answer (score 2):

You can find spring security Jars here http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security for all version

If you want other components of spring i.e jar you can browse through the same link by removing /security/spring-security enter in browser bar and search for other respective index you want by version.

Comment: Link requires login